# Simulate a button click via JavaScript using a button's value, not its id?

Tags: javascript, button, click

I want to Simulate a button click via JavaScript using a button's value, not its id.

Here is the code using the button id

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="document.getElementById('theSubmitButton').click();">Check the box to simulate a button click
<br>
<input type="button" name="theSubmitButton" id="theSubmitButton" value="Button" onClick="alert('The button was clicked.');">
```

I've tried getElementByValue('Button') but it didn't work.

Comment: It works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/R27rQ/.

Comment: @pimvdb That solution still uses the id.

Comment: @jncraton: I misunderstood the question. Didn't see what 'no't' meant.

Comment: not sure why you want to do this, but it doesn't work for me in OS X Lion and Chrome. As in, the alert appears but the button click is not animated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getButtonByValue(value) {
        var els = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (var i = 0, length = els.length; i < length; i++) {
            var el = els[i];

            if (el.type.toLowerCase() == 'button' && el.value.toLowerCase() == value.toLowerCase()) {
                return el;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
</script>    
<input type="checkbox" onClick="getButtonByValue('Button').click();">Check the box to simulate a button click
<br>
<input type="button" name="theSubmitButton" id="theSubmitButton" value="Button" onClick="alert('The button was clicked.');">
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zTLGB/)

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I'd do it using jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/skilldrick/R27rQ/1/

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
    $('input[value=Button]').click();
});
```

but as Senad said, IDs are much better-suited for this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
    function clickButton(val)
    {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
      for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) 
      {
         if(buttons[i].type == 'button' && buttons[i].value == val) 
         {
              buttons[i].click();
              break; //this will exit for loop, but if you want to click every button with the value button then comment this line
         }
      }
}
```

this is solution...

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="clickButton('Button');">Check the box to simulate a button click
```

But its best to find element by its ID